# Matching Regex in Document

Tags: javascript, regex

If location.href.match(i) matches in the URL,

how do you use javascript to match for something throughout the entire document without jquery?

Comment: What is "throughout the entire document"? And what kind of result do you want to get? (`"string".matches(regex)` returns an array, for example.)

Comment: You need to define "match something". There are several approaches depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was trying document.body.match(i)  with var i =/regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `res=document.body.innerHTML.match(i);`. And if you want include the head part of the document: `document.documentElement.innerHTML...`.